# «Не замерзающий» — как объяснить раздельное написание?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, причастия

*Зимою **не замерзающий** залив бывает заселен многими миллионами налетной птицы.*

*Не замерзающий* — причастие, в словаре даётся слитно с частицей НЕ.
Почему в этом предложении надо писать раздельно?

Comment: Птица-миллионер в приложении...

Comment: Раиса, я бы поставила запятую после причастия, тогда получился бы причастный оборот, "не" писалось бы раздельно, т.к. есть зависимое слово. Обособление, потому что есть добавочное значение причины: так как залив не замерзает, к нему устремляются все птицы и живут там.

Comment: Налётные туманы, налётные черти... Термина из приведённого текста Гугл не знает. Возможно, что это ещё одна опечатка: птицы бывают (в отношении способности летать) перелётные, осёдлые и «нелётные», они же нелетающие. И ещё: если птицы «заселили залив», значит они прилетели и устроились там, а не налетели.

Answer (score 1):

Два возможных варианта написания соответствуют разным смыслам.

Версия 1. Если исходить из имеющегося *раздельного* написания, то зависимое слово "зимою" указывает на то, что именно зимой залив не замерзает (а когда же он замерзает?), и этот залив  время от времени (неясно, когда и почему) "бывает" заселён птицами, которые грамматически трактуются собирательно (птица), но сосчитаны почему-то штучно (миллионы). Общий смысл здесь странный.

Версия 2. Если исправить на *слитное* написание, то "незамерзающий" становится прилагательным, характеризующим свойство залива вне времён года (он в принципе "незамерзающий"). При этом птицы заселяют "незамерзающий" залив исключительно *зимой*, но не всегда, хотя такое "бывает". Тоже не очень понятно, но более правдоподобно.

Answer (score 1):

Правильное предложение выглядит так ([И. С. Соколов-Микитов. У синего моря](http://blue-days.narod.ru/28.htm)):

> Зимою **незамерзающий** залив бывает населен многими миллионами налётной птицы, часть которой отлетает дальше к берегам Ирана, а часть остается на зимовку.

Слово [**налётный**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/31208/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) (МАС), конечно же, есть (а в словарной статье наше предложение приведено в качестве примера):
**2.** *Устар.* То же, что перелетный (о птицах).
*Зимою **незамерзающий** залив бывает населен многими миллионами налетной птицы, часть которой отлетает дальше к берегам Ирана, а часть остается на зимовку* (Соколов-Микитов. У синего моря).

Речь идет о заливе (Кизыл-Агач, Кызыл-Агач, [Кызылагадж](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6_(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2)) (Азербайджан)), который никогда не замерзает. Смысл предложения таков: незамерзающий залив бывает населен зимою...
Так что правильное написание — слитное (Кольский залив тоже относится к незамерзающим).

*Наша цель, к которой мы всегда стремились, — поиски на его берегах удобных, незамерзающих гаваней и установление дружбы с туземцами, в чем мы преуспели за два года* (Н. П. Задорнов. Война за океан).

Answer (score 1):

Корректно слитное написание (как я вам уже ответил на другом форуме), так как здесь нет ни зависимых слов, ни противопоставлений. Слово «зимою» не является зависимым словом при причастии. Речь идёт о заливе, который зимой населен миллионами налетной птицы. А вот при таком порядке слово «зимою» было бы зависимым при причастии.

Не замерзающий зимою залив... Залив (какой?) не замерзающий зимою.